# using youtube_it gem in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, uploading

i'm using ruby-1.8.7 and rails 2.3.5 in my rails app. i have a requirement to let the users upload their videos to youtube for which i'm using youtube_it gem. But i'm not sure if i'm following the documentation right.

here's my controller code:

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController

  def upload
    @upload_info = YouTubeIt::Client.new.upload_token(params, videos_url)
# params represent what values here, the doc says title, description but do i have to #build another form to get these values, i really need a working example. 
  end
```

and here's my form:

```
  <% form_tag @upload_info[:url], :multipart => true do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :token, @upload_info[:token] %>
    <%= label_tag :file %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag "Upload video" %>
  <% end %>
```

my other question is where am i supposed to specify the following statement which will initialize a new client for me:

```
client = YouTubeIt::Client.new(:dev_key => "developer_key")
```

i need some assistance here.

Answer (score 0):

you are close just is missing a first step for give title and description to the video

for example

1 step) ask for title and description

send this to the controller and call to the method

```
@upload_info = YouTubeIt::Client.new.upload_token(params[:first_step], videos_url)
```

and this has to call to second step

2 step) the form that do you had

```
 <% form_tag @upload_info[:url], :multipart => true do %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag :token, @upload_info[:token] %>
   <%= label_tag :file %>
   <%= file_field_tag :file %>
   <%= submit_tag "Upload video" %>
 <% end %>
```

I going to give you a gist with real example

https://gist.github.com/1051122

for the last question you can initialize the client in your application_controller.rb, you can see it in the gist

I hope that it help you, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

here you have a code example

http://www.chebyte.com/2011/09/15/youtube-it-demo-rails-app/